# Restrict domain of variance in Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Let's say I have a point $a \in \mathcal{U}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is a set, and $x$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Is it mathematically correct to say:

Restrict $\sigma^2$ sufficiently small such that $a + x \in \mathcal{U}$ (or, probability of $a + x \not\in \mathcal{U}$ is 0); $a + x$ always stay in $\mathcal{U}$.

Thank you.

Comment: This will only happen in the limit as $\sigma^2\to 0$. In this limit, your Gaussian dist. will "converge" to a delta function which will have probability of one of being inside U (since it is the PDF of a constant (degenerate) random variable.

Comment: I should add if U is the real line or the real line minus a countable subset of the reals then there is no need to take the limit since a linear transformation of a Gaussian random variable is again Gaussian and thus real-valued.

Comment: And to answer your question directly, the answer is no it would not be correct to say "Restrict $\sigma^2$ sufficiently small..." because if U is not the reals (or reals minus a countable subset) then $a+x$ will always have nonzero probability outside U.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you for your reply! Then, to clarify, even if $U = [0, 4]$, and $a = 2$, $a+x$ will have nonzero probability outside $U$ and I need to take the limit.

Comment: That is correct. $a+x$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $a$ and variance $\sigma^2$ so to get the probability of $a+x$ being outside of U just integrate the PDF of $a+x$ over U and subtract result from 1.

Comment: See link below for exact probability of being outsode U= [0,4]. You can plug in values to get probabilities.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-Integrate%5BPDF%5BNormalDistribution%5Ba%2C%CF%83%5E2%5D%2Cx%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C4%7D%5D